# sum a column value (int) to a datetime column mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns: start_date(DATETIME), bid (int to relation with other table), journeys (int with number of days to sum)... and I need sum the journeys value to datetime (every row can have a different journeys deffined)

practical example that I want:

for example I have:

> Start_date (2016-11-05 00:00:00), bid (17), journeys (5)
>
> Start_date (2016-10-09 00:00:00), bid (19), journeys (9)

My query for now:

```
update dates SET start_date= DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 10 DAY) where inicio_jor >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

I don't know how can I get the values 10 (journeys*2) and 5 (journeys) from a subquery

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
update dates SET start_date = DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL journeys*2 DAY) where start_date >= (CURDATE() - journeys DAY);
```